# problem with retrieve time (String) to set alarm from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to an alarm app that retrieve time value from database(Firestore), which I store as String, but it throws NullPointerException in my onTimeSet method, I don't know what else to do.

This is my method (dbAlarmManager).

```
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private dbReminder tt;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alarmmanager);

    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    db.collection("Reminder").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                        for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                            dbReminder p = d.toObject(dbReminder.class);
                            p.setId(d.getId());
                            remtasklist.add(p);
                            onTimeSet();   }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void onTimeSet(){

    String strtime = tt.getTime();
    String[] parts = strtime.split(":");
    String part1 = parts[0];
    String part2 = parts[1];

    int hr = Integer.parseInt(part1);
    int min = Integer.parseInt(part2);

    final int _id = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(dbAlarmManager.this, mainPlan.AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(dbAlarmManager.this, _id, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

    Log.i(TAG, "Time to alarm is " + part1 + ":" + part2);

}
```

dbReminder.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class dbReminder implements Serializable {

@Exclude
private String id;

private String time;

public dbReminder(String title, String desc, String inLocation, String objPerson, String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
public dbReminder() {
    //empty constructor needed

}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
```

This is my logcat.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.asus.robot.onzenbo.dbReminder.getTime()' on a null object reference
    at com.asus.robot.onzenbo.dbAlarmManager.onTimeSet(dbAlarmManager.java:62)
    at com.asus.robot.onzenbo.dbAlarmManager.access$100(dbAlarmManager.java:21)
    at com.asus.robot.onzenbo.dbAlarmManager$1.onSuccess(dbAlarmManager.java:49)
    at com.asus.robot.onzenbo.dbAlarmManager$1.onSuccess(dbAlarmManager.java:39)
```

Thanks in advance! I don't know what else put in, you guys can ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize `dbReminder` before using it, like :

`String strtime = tt.getTime();`

Comment: how do you initialize tt? can you provide me your code?

Comment: I did the same as you suggested. but do you mean that I have to declare strtime inside dbReminder too? I'm sorry though, i'm still a newb at this thing.

Comment: Add:   tt = new dbReminder("YOUR ARGUMENTS"); above db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();